# Sort By Soundex (or similar) `Closeness`

Tags: mysql, sorting, soundex

Is there any way to have MySQL order results by how close they 'sound' to a search term?

I'm trying to order fields that contain user input of city names. Variations and misspellings exist, and I'd like to show the 'closest' matches at the top.

I know soundex may not be the best algorithm for this, but if it (or another method) could be reasonable successful - it may be worth having the sorting done by the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soundex is no good for this sort of thing because different words can give you the same Soundex results and will therefore sort arbitrarily. A better solution for this is the Levenshein Edit Distance algorithm and you may be able to implement it as a function in your database: Link to [Levensheint impl. as MySql stored function](http://www.supermind.org/blog/927/working-mysql-5-1-levenshtein-stored-procedure)!!!

You can also check out this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql). It contains a Sql server (T-SQL-specific) implementation of the algorithm but it should be possible to port. The mechanics of the algorithm are fairly simple needing only a 2D array and looping over string.

Comment: I was looking at Levenshtein if I had to do the sorting in the code. Seems like it weighing implementing the *correct* algorithm in the database, or using the same algorithm that's already available on the code side of things.

Comment: If you implement it as a MySql function (link in answer) then you should be able to do it in your SQL. Something like: SELECT CityName, Leven(CityName, compString) FROM City ORDER BY Leven(CityName, compString)

Comment: @Rinzler: Yeah, this post is almost two years old. Links disappear. In any case, I found another example of a MySql implementation and relinked.

Comment: thanks my friend , can you find me a soundex implemetation in zend framework

Comment: @Rinzler: Check out this PHP manual page for working with Levenshtein: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php I'm not familiar with Zend but you should be able to leverage the algorithm.