# How to sort the results with reference to the keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, relevance

I am developing a classifieds site. For searching product or company I am using wildcard (%) in both in front and back.

```
$keyword = "%".$user_keyword."%";
```

And I am using the following mysql query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT   login.id_user,  
                login.company,
                login.district,
                FROM login LEFT JOIN products 
                ON login.id_user = products.id_user
                WHERE   (login.district LIKE ? 
                    AND login.place LIKE ?)
                        AND
                    (login.company LIKE ?
                    OR login.summary LIKE ?
                    OR products.description LIKE ?)
                LIMIT ?, ?";    
                ";
```

This is working. But I want to sort the list with reference to the keyword.
For eg: If an user search for "foo" the following result may be get:

```
fool
kafoo
safoora
foo
foolan
```

I want to get "foo" as the first item

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980638/sort-by-soundex-or-similar-closeness

Answer (score 1):

Please try following:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT   login.id_user,  
                login.company,
                login.district,
                FROM login LEFT JOIN products 
                ON login.id_user = products.id_user
                WHERE   (login.district LIKE ? 
                    AND login.place LIKE ?)
                        AND
                    (login.company LIKE ?
                    OR login.summary LIKE ?
                    OR products.description LIKE ?)
                order by if(LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.district)=0, 9999, LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.district))+
                         if(LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.place)=0, 9999, LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.place))+
                         if(LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.company)=0, 9999, LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.company))+
                         if(LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.summary)=0, 9999, LOCATE('$user_keyword', login.summary))+
                         if(LOCATE('$user_keyword', products.description)=0, 9999, LOCATE('$user_keyword', products.description))
                LIMIT ?, ?";    
                ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need exact match to appear as the first one in the result, then you should add something like this to your query:

```
[...]
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN checked_column = 'keyword' THEN 1  /* exact match */
    ELSE 2  /* non-exact match */
  END,
  checked_column  /* sort non-exact matches */
```

But if you need a more sophisticated sorting like scoring your results to reflect how similar they are to a given keyword, then the concept you are looking for is called [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).