# Select name matching like 80%

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to found the fraud customer's , the customer name which are all matching 80% with the fraudulent customer's name. So any one give idea for pattern check. I think this explanation is sufficient to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for this see [Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)

The example is in T-sql but you can use it to see the pattern

Answer (score 3):

There are set of standard algorithmns which will help you to acheive the requirement like ..

1. Levenstein
2. JaroWinkler
3. NeedlemanWunch
4. SmithWaterman
5. ChapmanLengthDeviation..

Comment: Thanks friends ... really these concepts are new to my life... thanks fr a valuable suggetion.. i will try this now..

Answer (score 0):

I just created a SQLCLR library for running Levenshtein on Sql Server [here](https://bitbucket.org/vgrit/clrsquirrel). Feel free to contribute. :)