# TSQL Degrees of Difference in strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to compare 2 strings in a sql statement. Some of the string are almost identical and some are very different

For example:

The following 2 addresses are almost identical

```
22224 143RD AVE 
222-24 143RD AVE.
```

While the next 2 are very different

```
6969 elmund street 
6969 mamerth street
```

Is there a function to classify the degree of difference?

Comment: One way of measuring similarity is called Levenshtein distance. There's a good q & a here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100365 lays out `DIFFERENCE()` and `SOUNDEX()`.  I'm not sure how well these would work in your particular use case.