# SQL Query to return results if user entered "ABCD-EFGH" instead of "ABCDEFGH"

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, search

I am using SQL Server 2008 and need to write a query that should return a record of `ABCDEFGH` if a user enters a search string such as `ABCD-EFGH` or `ABDEFGH` etc (i.e. records that are similar to).

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Maybe you want to look at the built-in function `DIFFERENCE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx I am not sure it would help you in this specific case, but it might do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to employ some sort of editDistance algorithm i.e  Levenshtein distance ,Jaro–Winkler distance to calculate the difference between 2 strings.

look at this thread  for Levenshtein distance implemented as udf

[Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)

you will use the UDF like this (just an example)

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE   dbo.editDistance(mycol,@SearchString)<2
```