# Finding Potential Duplicates With hyphens or dashes in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I am trying to find potential duplicates in my database.
Some people might have a duplicate since they have added a "-" into their name or last name (for which ever reason).
My query currently does not pull people who might have a duplicate of someone with a "-".
What might be the best way to do this?

This is my query so far

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.ID, t2.dupeCount
FROM Contact t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT FirstName, REPLACE(LastName, '-', ' ') as LastName, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount
    FROM Contact
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 ON ((SOUNDEX(t1.LastName) = SOUNDEX(t2.LastName) 
OR SOUNDEX(REPLACE(t1.LastName, '-', ' ')) like '%' + SOUNDEX(t2.LastName) + '%'  
OR SOUNDEX(REPLACE(t2.LastName, '-', ' ')) like '%' + SOUNDEX(t1.LastName) + '%' )
AND SOUNDEX(t1.FirstName) = SOUNDEX(t2.FirstName))
ORDER BY t1.LastName, t1.ID
```

Comment: Is this data you can correct, or is it 'read only'?

Comment: I can correct the data, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot more involved than something you can fix in one Select statement.  When I run into this, I create a stored procedure and trim off leading and trailing spaces, remove punctuation that shouldn't be there (such as in middle names that are abbreviated some of the time and not other times), and check to see if phone numbers, address/zip code combinations, and/or email addresses point to the same person.  Soundex helps, but it isn't enough.

Comment: I am only interested in outputting every and any potential duplicates found in the database, just for reporting purposes. My query is a bit longer since it outputs the email address, company and group that they are involved with. I only need to compare the name and last name of the person for now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a Levenshtein distance algorithm would be useful, this measures the number of edits you would need to make to a string to make it the same as another string. In Oracle there is a built in function called edit_distance under the utl_match library, but I don't know of a built in version in SQL Server.

I did a quick Google search for Levenshtein distance and Edit distance SQL Server and found the following stack overflow thread among other results that may be helpful:
[Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)

If you are able  to create a function that you can call to get the Levenshtein distance then you can just filter the query on whether the distance < x, setting the threshold as you see fit.

Comment: I have just taken another look at your query. For the hyphen case that you mentioned, this should work if you change: "REPLACE(t1.LastName, '-', ' ')" to "REPLACE(t1.LastName, '-', '')". However, if you can get the Levenshtein algorithm to work this will allow for other unforeseen differences. I would also advise converting the case to upper or lower on both sides of the join unless you are certain that the case is consistent for all of the names.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. I will definitely take a look at that algorithm. I might ask for your help later though :)

Comment: Looking through the algorithm you posted, how would it work with hyphenated names? Since @d is the parameter for the max distance it should take, this parameter then should then vary for each last name.
So if you have smith and smith-doe, would it then have 4 to be the distance from smith to smith-doe? what about smith and smyth? smith and smith-johnson? I'm just trying to figure out what would be the appropriate @d to use.