# Match a large number of records in a database?

Tags: sql, .net, lucene

I need match about 25 million address records with about 200,000 other address records. I also would like to have a small degree of fuzziness so comparing for exact matches is kind of out. The addresses are parsed into components in both data sets. And they are both stored in a SQL Server 2008 database.

I had an idea to do comparisons in batches (grouping the batches by state) until I reached the end, dumping matches into a temporary database. This would be done in a .NET application, but I don't think this is too efficient since I have to pull the data from SQL into the application and iterate over it one by one. Threading could speed up the process, but I don't know by how much.

I also thought about indexing the 25 million records into a Lucene index and utilizing the filtering in that to trim narrow down potential matches.

Are either of these a good approach? What other options are there?

Answer (score 0):

For a first pass do an exact

For fuzzy you can use Levenstien Distance

[Levenstien Distance TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)

You can also run Levenstien in .NET
It might make sense to bring the 200,000 into a .NET collection
And then compare the 25 million one at a time to the 200,000
I assume the .NET implementation is faster just don't know how much faster.

[C# Levenshtein](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)

MSSQL has SOUNDEX but it is way to fuzzy.

Hopefully you have a valid state to filter on

Hopefully you have a some valid zip code
If the zip code is valid then filter to only that zip code