# Edit distance similarity sas?

Tags: sas

I have a list of domains in a table V_tablas.arreglo(columns--> domainsBad):
   `@hotmai.es
    @ghotmail.es
    @hotmaol.com
    @hotmai.com
    @otmail.com.....etc(more than 10k)`
And need to correct this domains to "@hotmail.com"
My questions is about EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY(fuzzy logic) of oracle for get 'Returns an integer Between 0 and 100, Where 0 Indicates no similarity at all and 100 Indicates a perfect match' Is it posible?

Answer (score 1):

SAS has at least a couple functions for calculating edit distance between two strings:

Compged, for general edit distance:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002206133.htm

Complev, for Levenshtein distance:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002206137.htm

Comment: Don't forget `SPEDIS()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Levenshtein distance algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to work out the number of edits to convert the source to the destination strings.

An implementation in SQL is described in this answer:

[Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)