# Check if similar value exists in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to check if an equal or a similar value exists in database.
I have build this code:

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection();
con1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChipstarALConn"].ToString();

string sql1 = "select Count(*) from SMS_KOD where KOD = @name";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con1);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
con1.Open();

int result = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
if (result > 0)
{
    Lab0.Text = "true";
}
else
{
    Lab0.Text = "false";
}
```

And it returns `true`. Now I want to return `true` if a `string` entered on `TextBox` is entered wrong but similar.
For example if a value in Database is `ASDFG` and I put on `TextBox` `ASDFH` or `AXDFG` it must also return `true`.

Comment: What is the criteria? Should it be true in any wrong value is entered, and false for correct ones, or do you have some other logic in mind?

Comment: If the value in the database is "ASDFG" and the user enters "AXDFG", in what way is that true, they don't match. Do you want use some kind of fuzzy matching algorithm? If so this is too broad for an SO question.

Comment: What is `TextBox1.Text` Is this MVC or Webforms?

Comment: I guess he wants string relatives, where one character doesn't violate equation.

Comment: Do You want Start with And End with that pattern ???

Comment: What I want is that if a user puts a character wrong in a string it still must return true.

Comment: I've surprisingly become telepathic. thanks SO :)

Comment: @IsThatSo, Whats this weeks winning lottery numbers?

Comment: Come on guys. :P Can I get any help? I got it to work by String.Replace method by comparing 2 strings from 2 Textboxes but I want now from Database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here's a list of numbers: 2 6 13 19 20 21 24 33 38 40. you need to select substrings of them. or you can refer to http://anastasiosyal.com/POST/2009/01/11/18.ASPX

Comment: you can traverse string till the string length. And if string does not match more than one character it will return false otherwise true. you can maintain a counter for that for the unmatched characters.

Comment: P.S. I found the right answer. You did nor have to put on hold. Mr. @Tim Schmelter answered it. And I marked his answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Levenshtein distance algorithm in T-SQL. For example (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Levenshtein(@s nvarchar(4000), @t nvarchar(4000), @d int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sl int, @tl int, @i int, @j int, @sc nchar, @c int, @c1 int,
    @cv0 nvarchar(4000), @cv1 nvarchar(4000), @cmin int
  SELECT @sl = LEN(@s), @tl = LEN(@t), @cv1 = '', @j = 1, @i = 1, @c = 0
  WHILE @j <= @tl
    SELECT @cv1 = @cv1 + NCHAR(@j), @j = @j + 1
  WHILE @i <= @sl
  BEGIN
    SELECT @sc = SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1), @c1 = @i, @c = @i, @cv0 = '', @j = 1, @cmin = 4000
    WHILE @j <= @tl
    BEGIN
      SET @c = @c + 1
      SET @c1 = @c1 - CASE WHEN @sc = SUBSTRING(@t, @j, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      IF @c > @c1 SET @c = @c1
      SET @c1 = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j, 1)) + 1
      IF @c > @c1 SET @c = @c1
      IF @c < @cmin SET @cmin = @c
      SELECT @cv0 = @cv0 + NCHAR(@c), @j = @j + 1
    END
    IF @cmin > @d BREAK
    SELECT @cv1 = @cv0, @i = @i + 1
  END
  RETURN CASE WHEN @cmin <= @d AND @c <= @d THEN @c ELSE -1 END
END
GO
```

Now something like this works:

```
SELECT Kod, Levenshtein  = dbo.Levenshtein(Kod, @name, 2)
FROM SMS_KOD
WHERE dbo.Levenshtein(Kod, @name, 2) <> -1
```

You can use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`. If it contains rows there are at least similar `Kod`s.

[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5654c/2/0)

Here is a possible implementation:

```
string sql = @"SELECT Kod, Levenshtein = dbo.Levenshtein(Kod, @name, 2)
               FROM SMS_KOD
               WHERE dbo.Levenshtein(Kod, @name, 2) <> -1";

var table = new DataTable();
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
    da.Fill(table);

if(table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int equals = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Levenshtein") == 0).Count();
    if(equals > 0)
        Lab0.Text = string.Format("{0} equal found in database.", equals);
    else
    {
        int similars = table.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Levenshtein") != 0)
            .Count();
        Lab0.Text = string.Format("{0} similar found in database.", similars);
    }
}
else
    Lab0.Text = "No equal or similar found in database!";
```

Comment: Thank You. You've been helpful. Now I have to figure it out how to put it in my code above.
If that's ok for you can you give me a hand? Thank You.

Comment: @aldoblack: I've added a possible implementation.