# The most similar string

Tags: c#, indexing, similarity, fuzzy-search

I have about 1000 rows in the database. For my purpose I need to find the most similar from DB.

For example the DB has rows:

> England
>   Spain
>   English
>   French
>   France
>   Turkey
>   Ukrainian
>   .....
>   Scotland

and so on.

The source string I have, for example, English's(it's may be anything string, BUT about 95% it hasn't identical string in database, only similar.)

I have some algorithms that can find the most similar. It's based on one of [these Wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures).

How can I find the similar among this 1000 rows? Go through all rows - it's very long?
Maybe create index? Index of what items?

I need fresh thoughts.

UPDATE:

I didn't specify that it's the often-performed operations. It's perfomed in a loop of 50 and more items. And it's web app and I can't every time to access db. At first Time I select all rows, cache it in memory, and for next iterations I use data from cache. So I need do it in code(C#.NET)

Comment: Personally, I would write some code and see whether it fits my performance needs. If yes, I would be done, if not, I would try another algorithm and/or fire up some Performance Profiler tool.

Comment: Perhaps you could use  Levenshtein. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293285/check-if-similar-value-exists-in-database/27293721#27293721

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP's page already lists it among the algos.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "It's based on one of these" is not very specific. I wanted to show a working sample on a similar question. Maybe using a .NET version  is more efficient. http://levenshtein.blogspot.de/2011/04/how-it-is-done.html

Comment: @LB . . . I disagree that this is a duplicate question, but I can't post my answer because it was closed.  It seems inappropriate, but I put the answer on the other question.

Comment: Since you mention a DB, if it's sql server, couldn't you use DIFFERENCE to get the SOUNDEX difference between two strings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx You wouldn't even need to fetch or iterate, just query for the closest to your input.