# The number of differences in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to retrieve a column of how many differences in letters in each row. For instance

If you have a a value "test" and another row has a value "testing ", then the differences is 4 letter between "test" and "testing ". The data of the column would be value 4

```
I have reflected about it and I don't know where to begin

id    ||  value     || category   || differences 
--------------------------------------------------
 1    ||  test      || 1          || 4
 2    ||  testing  || 1          || null   
11    ||  candy     || 2          || -3       
12    ||  ca        || 2          || null
```

In this scenario and context it is no difference between "Test" and "rest".

Comment: Wouldn't your differences be 3 for ID 1 and -3 for ID 11?

Comment: So no difference between `test` and `rest`?

Comment: You have one white space in id 2 and yes your are right it is supposed to be -3 in id 11. My bad

Comment: In this scenario and context it is no difference between Test and rest.

Comment: Is the category of any significance here, i.e. must 'test' and 'testing' be in the same category in order to be compared?

Comment: @KLN Do check my answer

Comment: If there is not difference between "Test" and "rest" then a simple difference in length and this is one poorly written question.  How is the difference in test and testing 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a measure of [edit difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), rather than just counting prefix similarity, for which there are a few common algorithms. [Levenshtein's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is one that I've used before and I've seen it implemented as TSQL functions. The answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) suggest a couple of implementations in TSQL that you might just be able to take and use as-is.

<sup>(though take time to test the code and understand the method rather than just copying the code and using it, so that you can understand the output if something seems to go wrong - otherwise you could be creating some technical debt you'll have to pay back later)</sup>

Exactly which distance calculation method you want will depend on how you want to count certain things, for instance do you count a substitution as one change or a delete and an insert, and if your strings are long enough for it to matter do you want to consider substring moves, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `len()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.id, t.value, t.category,
       (len(lead(value) over (partition by t.category order by t.id) -
        len(value)
       ) as difference
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp
(
id int,
value varchar(30),
category int
)

insert into #temp
select 1,'test',1
union all
select 2,'testing',1
union all
select 1,'Candy',2
union all
select 2,'Ca',2

;with cte
as
(
select id,value,category,lead(value) over (partition by category order by id) as nxtvalue
from #temp
)
select id,value,category,len(replace(nxtvalue,value,'')) as differences
from cte
```

Comment: I tried your code and I retrieve a message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: @KLN: If the message says "previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon" I'd humbly suggest you terminate the previous statement with a semicolon (the one before `with` obviously). And anyway, TheGameiswar is only building a temp table as an example. Are you using this? Don't you have a *real* table to work with?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have a real table

Comment: Dont worry, I have areal table

Comment: i have changed it,CTE should start with a semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

You read a next record with `LEAD`. Then compare the strings with LIKE or other string functions:

```
select
  id, value, category,
  case when value like next_value + '%' or next_value like value + '%' 
       then len(next_value) - len(value)
  end as differences
from
(
  select id, value, category, lead(value) over (order by id) as next_value 
  from mytable
) this_and_next;
```

If you only want to compare values within the same category use a partition clause:

```
lead(value) over (partition by category order by id)
```

**UPDATE:** Please see **DhruvJoshi's** answer on SQL Server's `LEN`. This function doesn't count trailing blanks, as I assumed, so you need his trick in case you want to have them counted. Here is the doc on `LEN` confirming this behaviour: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score -1):

you can also use self joining query like below:

```
--create table tbl (id int,  value nvarchar(100), category int);
--insert into tbl values
--(1,N'test',1)
--,(2,N' testing',1)
--,(11,N'candy',2)      
--,(12,N'ca',2);
select A.*, LEN(B.value)-LEN(A.value) as difference
from tbl A LEFT JOIN tbl B on A.id +1 =B.id and A.category=B.category
--drop table tbl
```

**Update:** I noticed that you have oddly positioned the space at the end. SQL server most times does not count the trailing spaces when calculating length. So here's the hack on above query

```
select A.*, LEN(B.value+'>')-LEN(A.value+'>') as difference
from tbl A LEFT JOIN tbl B on A.id +1 =B.id and A.category=B.category
```

As pointed out in comments, that Id's may not be consecutive, in such cases
try this :

```
create table #temp ( rownum int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), id int, value nvarchar(100), category int)
insert into #temp (id, value, category)
select id, value, category from tbl order by id asc


    select A.id, A.value, A.category, LEN(B.value+'>')-LEN(A.value+'>') as difference
    from #temp A LEFT JOIN #temp B on A.rownum +1 =B.rownum and A.category=B.category
```

Comment: Oh, interesting that SQL Server doesn't count trailing blanks. I didn't know that. This is most valuable information in this context. Your query assumes that IDs are consecutive. One should better never make such assumptions when working with IDs, however.