# Differences between two data from different column

Tags: sql-server

Goal:
Retrieve a column of how many differences in letters in each row. For instance

If you have a value "test" and another row has a value "testing ", then the differences is 4 letter between "test" and "testing ". The data of the column would be value 4

I have reflected about it and I don't know where to begin

```
id    ||  value     || category   || differences 
--------------------------------------------------
 1    ||  test      || a          || 4
 2    ||  testing   || b          || null   
11    ||  candy     || a          || -2       
12    ||  ca        || b          || null
```

Thank you!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [The number of differences in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36863484) by the same author.