# matching names that are close by not always exact

Tags: sql, excel, macros

attempting to match a list of names that are similar in one very long column to another that are close but often vary do to missing letters and punctuation?  is there a simple solution via a macro and/or sql?

Comment: and good afternoon/evening/morning

Answer (score 0):

using Levenstein functions can help
check the function and algorithm here: [Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)

after you create a function - compare the distance, for example:

```
select ..... from....
where dbo.Levenstein(str1,str2)>0.9 --means, the match between str1 and str2 is 90%
```