# Using SQL Server Management Studio to compare Excel workbooks

Tags: sql-server, excel, crm

I need some suggestions on comparing a few different workbooks. I have a final one that has 4 sheets, Verified contacts, removed contacts, Unverified Contacts, and not on any tabs. The other two that I have, I will need to compare the records with the final one and determine what the final workbook is missing.

The main issue that I have found is I don't have a common denominator. The closest thing I can see is the Name field. The final workbook has A full name field. The other two work books separate the name out. Now I can concatenate them to create a full name, but I may still be missing a middle initial, or someone may be using a nickname. I need a reliable way to compare these workbooks. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a VERY common problem with no good solution. Your data is poor so your solution will be ugly.

Comment: you would have to use a programming language like Python and have it do matching with some level of error.  See stuff like fuzzywuzzy or levenshtein distance.  It won't be perfect but might be close enough.

Comment: You could implement a [levenshtein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) function in SQL Server, which is not totally uncommon, and join on the results of that (result > .90, for instance). It will be slow, but it's a decent start.

Comment: I'll look into it, Thanks!