# select records which contains nearby word in string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch record which contains similar word in string.I know %% trick in mysql to fetch required data like

```
select * from products where Name like '%LORFAST%'
```

but what if dont have exact word for filter??? like instead of "LORFAST" if i write "LORFST" then it will not return any record.

```
select * from products where Name like '%LORFST%'
```

**Expectation :**  even i miss any character it should return nearby match. above query should return "LORFAST TAB." any idea how to do that??

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30b949/2

**Code**

```
create table `products` (
    `Id` int (11),
    `Name` varchar (900)
); 
insert into `products` (`Id`, `Name`) values(1,'LORFAST TAB.');
insert into `products` (`Id`, `Name`) values(1,'SPORIDEX REDIMIX DROP');
insert into `products` (`Id`, `Name`) values(1,'MICROGEST 400MG');
insert into `products` (`Id`, `Name`) values(1,'ANTIPLAR PLUS TAB');
insert into `products` (`Id`, `Name`) values(1,'DECA DURABOLIN  100MG');
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). If that is so [here is the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql). You might need to tweak as per your needs.

Comment: Check out SOUNDS LIKE  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get some mileage from the `SOUNDEX` function.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT 'true'
FROM dual
WHERE SOUNDEX('LORFAST') LIKE SOUNDEX('LORFST');
```

This would output `true` because `SOUNDEX` is smart enough to detect that the two versions of `LORFAST` sound the same.

In the context of your sample data, let's say you wanted to search the names using `LORFST`, i.e. an abbreviated form of `LORFAST`.  Then we can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE SOUNDEX(Name) LIKE CONCAT('%',SOUNDEX('LORFST'),'%');
```

Follow the link below for a Fiddle of the above query.

As @Coder commented, using something like the Levenshtein distance might be a better general solution.

### Demo