# T-SQL - Average % of Matching Characters

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have data coming from two different systems which I input into two different tables in SQL Server 2016. These tables are related with a Key.

Table1

```
  Key       Name
  ------------------------
    1       Jim Parsons
    2       Steven Woz
    3       Billy Jean
    4       Carol Henderson
    5       Sara Hauder
```

Table2

```
   Key      Name
   ---------------------------
    1       Jimmy Parsons 
    2       Steven Wozniak
    3       Bill Jean
    4       Andy Smith
    5       Sara Hauder (a)
```

What I am hoping to develop is an additional column that will tell me if the `Name`s match. However, if the names are similar, I want to consider it a match.

In order to accomplish this I was thinking I could do something like

```
select 
    *,  
    case when a.Name like b.Name 1 else 0 
    end as Flag 
from 
    (Table1 a 
join 
    Table2 b on a.Key = b.Key)
```

But obviously this wouldn't work because even the slightest difference can cause a like statement to be false.

I'm not very familiar with how to find the longest common substring, but I don't actually care what the string is. What I'm thinking is I need to determine the average number/percentage of characters shared by the two fields and then say: if the number of characters shared between a.Name and b.Name is above or equal to the average, then 1 else 0. Not really sure how to go about this however...

AS an example: `Sara Hauder` should match with `Sara Hauder (a)`, but `Carol Henderson` should not match with `Andy Smith`. Note that many `Name`s will sometimes have some different tags at the end in parenthesis which can be filtered out if necessary. However, I am perfectly capable of adding this feature myself if you choose to ignore.

Comment: I would 100% implement a [levenshtein distance function in tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) and use that to give me the Levenshtein Distance between the two strings. Then base your flag on the result of that function tweaking what you consider to be a "match" as appropriate. Levenshtein distance is the tried and true way of doing "fuzzy" string comparison like this (there are others). I would definitely not try to come up with my own algorithm for doing this unless your usecase is VERY specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in .NET with [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It is a great measure of text similarity. You can just run it once and as records are added and it does not take very long.

I see you have a comment of the same.  I did not read it before posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real quick and dirty way using built in functions in MSSQL. This will not be perfect by any means, but it will get you pretty close.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1), name VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1), name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @table1 (name)
VALUES 
('Jim Parsons'),
('Steven Woz'),
('Billy Jean'),
('Carol Henderson'),
('Sara Hauder')

INSERT INTO @table2 (name)
VALUES 
('Jimmy Parsons'),
('Steven Wozniak'),
('Bill Jean'),
('Andy Smith'),
('Sara Hauder (a)')


SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN SOUNDEX(t1.name) = SOUNDEX(t2.name) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS name_match

FROM @table1 t1
INNER JOIN @table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: My experience is soundex is not very good for matching.  Still good answer.