# Compare Names using Levenshtein distance

Tags: sql-server, compare, levenshtein-distance, soundex

In my application i need to identify a person by searching for their lastname and firstname.  **One requirement is to accept spelling errors to a certain degree**.

My attempts to identify a person given a firstname and lastname were:

1. [sql query using soundex](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/843972/)
2. [sql query using levenshtein-distance](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844245/) (LD) which was calculated with this  [LD-function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/560733/819887)

The screenshot contains some test records and the result of my sql-query which includes the soundex-value for each column and the LD

[image: compare records using levenshtein distance]

My current query looks like this

```
SELECT t2.*
        , t1.Firstname + ' ' + t1.Lastname as SourceName
        , 'Torsten Mueller' as TargetName
        , dbo.FUNC_LEVENSHTEIN(t1.Firstname +' '+ t1.Lastname
                            , 'Torsten Mueller', 8) as LEVENSHTEIN_Distance     
 FROM #TestSoundex t1
 LEFT JOIN #TestSoundex t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
 WHERE t1.Soundex_Firstname = SOUNDEX('Torsten')
       AND t1.Soundex_Lastname = SOUNDEX('Mueller')
```

As you can see i filter the result by soundex first and calculate the levenshtein-distance for the remaining records.  In this sample below the levenshtein-distance ranges from 0 (both strings are equal) to 3.

```
SourceName       | TargetName      | Levenshtein Distance 
Thorsten Müller  | Torsten Mueller |  3 
Torsten Müller   | Torsten Mueller |  2
Thorsten Mueller | Torsten Mueller |  1
Torsten Mueller  | Torsten Mueller |  0
```

[In this talk from a stanford professor](https://youtu.be/Xxx0b7djCrs?t=155) the calculation for the distance is explained:

```
I N T E * N TION 
| | | | | | | 
* E X E C U TION
d s s   i s
```

Each deletion `d`, insertion `i` adds 1 point, a substitution `s` adds 2 points.
The `LD-function` i use returns 5 points for the sample above, but only 3 instead of 4 for the distance between `Thorsten Müller` and `Torsten Mueller`. 
I

```
+1 point to delete h, 
+1 point instead of 2 to substitute ü 
+1 point to insert e
```

So i added some samples

[image: Samples with Umlaut]

### Questions

My impression is that neither soundex nor LD are sufficient to uniquely identify a person-record given `firstname` and `lastname` and taking into account that there might be spelling mismatches.

- Can you explain how [this LD-Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/560733/819887) handles Umlaute `ü,ö,ä`so i can better understand the calculation?
- What would you recommend as a max value for the `distance` to find the right match for firstname and lastname given the string `s` and `t`, should it be based on the length of both strings `numberOrCharacters(s+t)/2 = max`?

#### Source Code

This is the function i use from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/560733/819887). I only changed the name of the function from `edit_distance_within` to `FUNC_LEVENSHTEIN`

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION FUNC_LEVENSHTEIN(@s nvarchar(4000), @t nvarchar(4000), @d int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sl int, @tl int, @i int, @j int, @sc nchar, @c int, @c1 int,
    @cv0 nvarchar(4000), @cv1 nvarchar(4000), @cmin int
  SELECT @sl = LEN(@s), @tl = LEN(@t), @cv1 = '', @j = 1, @i = 1, @c = 0
  WHILE @j <= @tl
    SELECT @cv1 = @cv1 + NCHAR(@j), @j = @j + 1
  WHILE @i <= @sl
  BEGIN
    SELECT @sc = SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1), @c1 = @i, @c = @i, @cv0 = '', @j = 1, @cmin = 4000
    WHILE @j <= @tl
    BEGIN
      SET @c = @c + 1
      SET @c1 = @c1 - CASE WHEN @sc = SUBSTRING(@t, @j, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      IF @c > @c1 SET @c = @c1
      SET @c1 = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j, 1)) + 1
      IF @c > @c1 SET @c = @c1
      IF @c < @cmin SET @cmin = @c
      SELECT @cv0 = @cv0 + NCHAR(@c), @j = @j + 1
    END
    IF @cmin > @d BREAK
    SELECT @cv1 = @cv0, @i = @i + 1
  END
  RETURN CASE WHEN @cmin <= @d AND @c <= @d THEN @c ELSE -1 END
END
GO
```

#### Source to test function above

This is another test

```
CREATE TABLE #TestLevenshteinDistance(
    Id int  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    SourceName nvarchar(100) NULL,  
    Soundex_SourceName varchar(4) NULL,    
    Targetname nvarchar(100) NULL, 
    Soundex_TargetName varchar(4) NULL, 
    );      

INSERT INTO #TestLevenshteinDistance 
    (    SourceName,          
         Soundex_SourceName,
         Targetname,
         Soundex_TargetName) 
VALUES 
   ('Intention',SOUNDEX('Intention'), 'Execution', SOUNDEX('Execution')),    
   ('Karsten' , SOUNDEX('Karsten'), 'Torsten', SOUNDEX('Torsten')); 


SELECT t1.*
        , dbo.FUNC_LEVENSHTEIN(t1.SourceName, t1.Targetname, 8) as LEVENSHTEIN_Distance
        FROM #TestLevenshteinDistance t1
```