# SELECT Statement For Finding Matching Phrases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of company names that I need to locate in the `Companies` table in our database.

The list of company names that I have are NOT precise. They could be misspelled. Some contain special characters, etc.

I'm trying to create a "fuzzy search" `SELECT` statement that will find the most likely matches in the `Companies` table. I'm doing some "sanitization" before sending names that need to be matched by trimming spaces in the beginning or end of words, removing words like "The", etc.

I tried the `FREETEXT` feature in SQL Server but the results were horrible. It pretty much returned all the rows in the `Companies` table.

For exmaple, I did a search for `1-800-Flowers` but got all kinds of unrelated hits. What approach can I use to find the most relevant matches?

Comment: There is no correct answer to this.   There's not even a "best" answer to it.

Comment: you could try [Fuzzy Lookup Transformation][1] in SSIS or 
[Excel fuzzyu matching][2]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/fuzzy-lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-2017
  [2]: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: Have you used LIKE eg: LIKE '%1%800%Flowers%'?

Comment: @ShankarDuvvuri `LIKE` is a very simple approach and fails easily. For example, if the order of words don't match, `LIKE` fails. Say, I'm searching for "Company, The" but in my database it's "The Company", then `LIKE` fails to return it.

Comment: @user1443098 Fuzzy Lookup Transformation seems interesting but never used it before. I'm looking into it so thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to implement something using the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

I found an implementation of the function in SQL Server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql).

Hope this helps.