# How to do bestmatch on a column in SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I am searching for a phone number in a column of a table. The length of the phone number happens to be longer than the ones present in the table.

In such a case how do I do a best match to get the column value which best coincides with my phone number?

Comment: Why is the type of your column CHAR or VARCHAR?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Which portion of the phone number is expected to be stored in the table? The begin, the end, something in between?

Comment: Example! I don't really get the problem.

Comment: Define `bestmatch`. Are you looking for fuzzy/partial matching? There's no such functionality in SQL Server. You can calculate the Edit distance between the stored numbers and the target, ie the number of digits that have to be added/removed/moved to get a match and find the one with the lowest distance. The [Levenshtein algorithm](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/) is a common way to do that, but it will be slow

Comment: One way to speed things up would be to calculate various permutations of the phone number on the *client* and search the database for them. For a 10 digit phone number, you'd generate 10 possible 9-digit phones and 110 11-digit phones.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a charindex to search if the value of column `phone` is present in your searchvalue

```
select * 
from   MyTable t
where  charindex(t.phone, '0123456789') > 0
```

this will find any rows where the contents of the column phone is inside '012345789'

another option is to use the `contains`function from full text search.
See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a function like [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

> Distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character
>   edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one
>   word into the other

There are a lot of implementation which differs in term of performance, see [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) and [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/) about this method

For example :

```
SELECT LEVENSHTEIN('0134227897', num) as distance , num
FROM   (VALUES ('0134752267'),
               ('+336709057'),
               ('+3347578974') ) AS t(num) 
order by distance
```

Result will be :

```
Distance   num  
5           +3347578974   
5           0134752267   
8           +336709057
```

So the best matchs are the two nums with only 5 of distance

Comment: This should be a commen. Yes, that's one option but that can't be used even to *start* implementing an answer. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) would be more appropriate as a *full* answer, or a SQLCLR function etc.

Comment: Or the full article [String Comparisons in SQL: Edit Distance and the Levenshtein algorithm](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find phone numbers that are longer than the others. You could find phone numbers that are longer than the average phone number like so:

```
SELECT phone_number
FROM my_tbl
WHERE LEN(phone_number) > (SELECT AVG(LEN(phone_number)) FROM my_tbl)
```

[`LEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) finds the length of a VARCHAR field

[`AVG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Is an aggregate function (a function that reduces a list down to a single value) that takes calculates the average of a list/column

---

P.s. I'm not certain what you mean by a 'best match' to get the value.