# How to fetch a row that matches the most similar sentence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to fetch a sql row that matches the most similar sentence entered by the user. 
For example user types
"Are you having fever"

and mysql table has records namely
1: "having, fever".
2: "fever"

It should fetch the number 1 record with it being the nearest match.

We have tried using LIKE, MATCH query like below one, but to no avail.

```
SELECT * FROM mbrace_pd.mbrace_pd WHERE MATCH(input) AGAINST ('Are you having fever');
```

How to do this?

Update: Okay it has started working partly. The "fever text" has started working. I added who,you content to the table and tried fetching it by typing who are you. But it did not work.

Comment: What problem did you have with `MATCH`?

Comment: It was not fetching the row as specified above.

Comment: It works fine for me in a small test case, can you edit your post with the query you used?

Comment: edited the post.

Comment: `input` is the column with the strings in it? Do you have a `FULLTEXT` index on `input`?

Comment: Yeah input is the column.Regarding fulltext I already did that with this sql query "ALTER TABLE mbrace_pd ADD FULLTEXT(input)"

Comment: What you have should work... it does in this small example: http://rextester.com/XZSO50783

Comment: Can you just tell me in what version of mysql sql MATCH works. Because the mysql version i have in the localhost is old.

Comment: Instead of saying it's "old" why not tell us what version it is?

Comment: It was introduced in 5.5

Comment: If you need proper way to get the closest matching value then you might need to look into [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You can implement it as a function and then use it [here is sql implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)