# Count of Character mismatch between two values in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to find the count of character mismatch between two values in a SQL Server stored procedure? It's not about the length difference.

For example, there are two values,

- Reference value ='Visual'
- Test value ='Visvolc'

Mismatch = 3 chars (4th, 5th and 7th position)

There is 3 character mismatch based on the position. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking for is “edit distance”, a number of add/remove/replace operation to convert one string into another. Check this post: [Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)