# Is there better way to use LIKE for multiple values in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Say there's a table `user` as below:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | char(64)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| img_hash | varchar(32)      | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I want to make a fuzzy match on field name, and there are multiple names in a list pending match as:

`["name1", "name2", "name3", ...]`

I'm tring to do with :

```sql
select 
    id, name, img_hash 
from
    user
where name like "%name1%" 
or name like "%name2%"
or name like "%name3%"
...
```

If there better way to do a fuzzy matching work in this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```
SELECT ID, NAME, IMG_HASH FROM USER 
WHERE NAME REGEXP 'name1|name2|name3'
```

More simpler version would be something like below. You can copy paste the names directly inside `CONCAT_WS`

```
SELECT ID, NAME, IMG_HASH FROM USER 
WHERE NAME REGEXP CONCAT_WS("|","name1", "name2","name3");
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b46d8d3a1c8d5a63f30b3ccdd59f2e4a)

*Please note that this may be slower than using `LIKE`*

Answer (score 0):

[Levenstein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) - How many changes required to convert one to another.

[Soundex()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_soundex.asp) - The SOUNDEX function converts a phrase to a four-character code. The first character is the first letter of the phrase. Vowels are omitted unless the first letter of the phrase is a vowel and the other three characters represent the rest of the phrase

[Difference()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_difference.asp) - Evaluates two expressions and assigns a value between 0 and 4, with 0 being little to no similarity and 4 representing the same or very similar phrases. This value is derived from the number of characters in the SOUNDEX of each phrase that are the same

[Comparison](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2159/using-soundex-and-difference-to-standardize-data-in-sql-server/)