# Is there an EF Core function (using SQL Server) to calculate levenshtein distance or a similar string comparison to sort a table by string similarity?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

I found `EF.Functions.TrigramsSimilarityDistance` at `https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql` for postgresql.

And I found a raw sql solution here:

[Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql)

I could use by implementing a stored procedure but I would prefer a SQL or EF function..

Comment: [Levenshtein distance in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql) has SQL solutions though.. What's wrong with them?

Comment: Create a T-SQL function then call it using function mapping https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what I will have to do, but I was hoping there was a solution with documentation/ support for instance included in a nuget package similar to the one for postgresql