# How to append multiple delta tables in a loop next to each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have few tables of the following format:

| Status | Date_2, Date_1 |
| --- | --- |
| Alive | 15 |
| Dead | -4 |
| Unknown | 25 |

| Status | Date_3, Date_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Alive | 56 |
| Dead | 44 |
| Unknown | -244 |

| Status | Date_4, Date_3 |
| --- | --- |
| Alive | 18 |
| Dead | 2 |
| Unknown | 5 |

And so on.

The final result should look like:

| Status | Date_2, Date_1 | Date_3, Date_2 | Date_4, Date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alive | 15 | 56 | 18 |
| Dead | -4 | 44 | 2 |
| Unknown | 25 | -244 | 5 |

How would I set up a Temp Table so that I could append the above data to it a loop so that they appear next to each other? The issue is that I already have @DynamicSQL which produces the above tables. All I want now is for them to be concatenated next to each other so that I don't have to copy them one by one into Excel to produce the necessary graphs.

Comment: As you've been advised in prior questions ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75072554/how-to-find-percentage-of-similarity-between-two-string-columns-in-a-table#comment132480095_75072554)) SSMS isn't a helpful tag here; it doesn't tell us what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Why is your dynamic SQL creating multiple datasets if you need them in one? Why not address this at the root of the problem?

Comment: @ThomA I would have addressed if I knew how. The easiest solution is for SSMS to simply produce and display those tables one by one. Sorry if this appeared to be rude.

Comment: @ThomA SQL Server.

Comment: What's the final result? some sort of pivot table with columns Date2, Date1, Date3, Date2, Date4, Date3?

Comment: Sounds like you need to update, not insert your temp table and dynamically determin the column to update based on the data source.

Comment: @Stu Is it possible to create a completely empty table and then perform update/ union all to it?

Comment: When you `CREATE` a table, @IsaacA , it is always empty.

Comment: *"The easiest solution is for SSMS to simply produce and display those tables one by one."* it would if your SQL returned a single dataset. Why not show us what you have and what you want to do; this looks like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Your current question provides your intermediate results and a vague description of your desire to combined the data without clearly defining what the final result should look like.  It would be better if your provided some initial sample data, the query you are using to produce your current results, and a sample of your desired final results.  I suspect that what you really need is a temp table with columns {Status, DateRange, Value} to hold all of you intermediate results. A final dynamic SQL query could then be constructed to perform a PIVOT. Excel can do pivots also.

Comment: It's fair to say that in the first instance, many people would prefer to improve your existing process to get what you want rather than incrementally cobble another piece to it. The short answer to your specific question is simply that you should use an inner join on "Status" to join those three tables. With that piece of information, do you have anything more specific to ask?

Comment: Do you always have all three rows?

Comment: @shawnt00 No. There rows here are just as an example.

Comment: Well if you don't always have the same rows for each column that's going to complicate things.

Comment: The reason for the dynamic SQL is so you can have data in the column headings? What tool are you using to report/view the output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible solution. Instead of trying to join the table next to each other, just add them on top of each other. But, to distinguish to which time period of each subsequent addition belongs to, add the new column in the table which shows the time period. Then just use the pivot table in Excel to get the data in the desired format. Will post code late.r

Answer (score -1):

Try this one,

```
 select coalesce(a.Status, b.Status,c.Status) as Status,
 a.Date1 as col1,
 b.Date2 as col2,
 c.Date3 as col3 
 from Table_1 as a,Table_2 as b,Table_3 as c
where a.Status = b.Status and a.Status = c.status
```